# python -- calling function in one script from another script when there are multiple functions

Tags: python, function

I currently have 2 scripts **test.py** and **connections.py**. **test.py** is currently being used to just test code to be able to incorporate into other scripts. **connections.py** contains a set of functions to create a MySQL connection, close connection, and execute SQL statement.

The connections.py is to be used by multiple scripts that need to connect to the database. I know how to call the appropriate function when within the same script and I know how to call a function in another script when there is only one function in the script.

What I can't figure out is how to call the right function when there are multiple functions. Through google/stackoverflow all the examples I have found are when there is only one function or the call is being made in the same script.

I have tried using a class with functions in it and just a file with functions. Code below is without class. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am also using python 3.5 on windows 10 and it will eventually be moved to a UNIX machine if that makes any difference.

**test.py**

```
import connections as c

sql = "select * from tbl"
sqlRec = c.select_stmt(sql)     # this is the command I need help with
print(sqlRec)
```

**connections.py**

```
import mysql.connector as MySQL

def connection():
    #set up connection
    con = MySQL.connect(user='xxx',password='xxx',host='xxx',db='xxx')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    return con, cursor

def close_connection(cursor,conn):
    cursor.close()
    con.close()

def select_stmt(sql):
    con, cursor = connection()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    sqlRec = cursor.fetchall()
    close_connection(cursor,con)
    return sqlRec

def insert_update_stmt(sql):
    con, cursor = connection()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    con.commit()
    close_connection(cursor,con)

#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    function_name_when_single_func(sql)  //With a single function I had these uncommented and this worked to run function from another script
```

Comment: Is the problem that it can't find the function? There's no reason this shouldn't work and I can't reproduce any issues.

Comment: Is there a specific error you're getting?  This code should work as written.

Comment: Samatha's suggestion below worked. I figured I was missing something simple. Yes, it appears it wasn't able to find the function

Comment: @soccergal_66
[David Beazley's tutorial on modules and packages](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0) is a great way to learn about the `import` statement.

Comment: @safay great! thanks! I will take a look. I have done a fair amount of programming in other languages, but my Python programming has been about 2 weeks at this point so still definitely learning all the nuances

Answer (score -4, accepted):

use `from file import *`
all the functions in that file should be callable

otherwise you can import specific functions e.g.
`from file import function`

Comment: When an import statement in the pattern of `from MODULE import *` is used it may become difficult for a Python validator to detect undefined names in the program that imported the module. Furthermore, as a general best practice, import statements should be as specific as possible and should only import what they need.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the functions you want in your import statement.
For example:

```
## connections.py
def foo():
    print("this is foo.")

def bar():
    print("this is bar.")

## test.py
from connections import foo, bar

foo()
bar()
```

`test.py` output:

```
this is foo.
this is bar.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Note**
It's best to be explicit about the imports you're bringing in from another module.
From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace.